# Report displaying subdatasheet

Tags: ms-access, report

I am trying to create a report in Access 2010 using a table 'Control_Points_Master_List'.

The 'Control_Points_Master_List' is a table with one column labeled 'Point_Designation'.  For each 'Point_Designation' record there is a subdatsheet with variable amount of subdatasheet records.  I want to create a report displaying all of the data found in the subdatasheet but cant seem to find a way to access the subdatasheet in the report design view.

Can anyone please help me understand the methodology to display a subdatasheet in a report?

Thanks,

dubbbdan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reports don't do sub datasheets, they do sub reports.

You'll need to create another report for `Point_Designation` and embed, as a subreport, that report in your master report. Link them appropriately on the Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields parameters.